# ember-data showing field from belongsTo relation after save

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have following model:

```rb
App.ApplianceType = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  description: DS.attr('string')
  author: DS.belongsTo('user')

  author_name: (->
    console.debug 'author >>> %o', @get('author')
    if @get('author') == null
      'anonymous'
    else
      @get('author.login')
  ).property 'author.login'

App.User = DS.Model.extend
  login: DS.attr('string')
  appliance_types: DS.hasMany('appliance_type', { inverse: 'author' })
```

Everything works as expected with one exception: after ApplianceType model is saved (`@get('content').save()`) `belongsTo` relation into author is set into author id instead of `author` model.

```
author >>> <App.User:ember427:3>                           //presenting appliance_type
PUT http://localhost:3000/api/v1/appliance_types/20 200 OK //saving appliance type
author >>> 3                                               //updating author login after save
```

Problem is connected with payload returned by the PUT invocation:

```rb
{"appliance_type":{
  "id":20,
  "name":"aaaasss",
  "description":"asdfasdfsd **aaaa**",   
  "author":3
}}
```

After the payload is changed into `{}` everything is OK - record is not updated. Is it expected behavior or bug in emberjs/ember-data?

emberjs `1.0.0`, ember-data `1.0.0.beta.2`

**Update**

I believe it is connected with: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1228

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a PR was pulled in last night that should fix this.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1257